# Setting with copy warning for a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to store the contents of a list inside of an empty column in my dataframe called "total_hour_activity" like seen bellow. However, I keep getting an a "setting with copy warning":

```
timestamp   date    activity    Id  total_hour_activity
720 00:00   2003-05-08  0   condition_1  NaN
721 00:01   2003-05-08  0   condition_1  NaN
722 00:02   2003-05-08  0   condition_1  NaN
723 00:03   2003-05-08  0   condition_1  NaN
724 00:04   2003-05-08  0   condition_1  NaN
... ... ... ... ... ...
10795   23:55   2003-05-14  12  condition_1 NaN
10796   23:56   2003-05-14  0   condition_1 NaN
10797   23:57   2003-05-14  18  condition_1 NaN
10798   23:58   2003-05-14  0   condition_1 NaN
10799   23:59   2003-05-14  64  condition_1 NaN


list = []
score = 0;
for i, row in my_df.iterrows():
    activity = i
    score = score + row['activity']
    if (i + 1) % 60 == 0:
        list.append(score)
        score = 0

my_df['total_hour_activity'] = list

<ipython-input-8-10e7d5921077>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- 
docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
 my_df['total_hour_activity'] = list
```

Is there another way to transfer the contents of a list to a dataframe column to avoid this warning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: How is your `my_df` created ?  Is it created as a slice from another dataframe ?  If so, this is a kind of hidden / indirect chaining assignment when you assign `list` to a column of it.

Comment: my_df is a modified copy of an original dataframe